# Skip first few words of a string when counting words in a text file

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to count the amount of words in a text file which has the following format:

```
TITEL####URL####ABSTRACT\n
TITEL####URL####ABSTRACT\n
TITEL####URL####ABSTRACT\n
```

like this:

```
 Available line####http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Available_line####In voice,
 Marwan al-Shehhi####http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marwan_al-Shehhi####Marwan etc.
 Theodore Beza####http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Beza####Theodore Beza etc.
```

My code to count the words looks like this:

```
    public static int countTotalWords() {
    totalWords = 0;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fis);

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            totalWords++;
            scan.next();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Opgave1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return totalWords;
}
```

I'm assuming that it works...

I want to only count the words in the abstract and therefore ignore the title and the URL. I'm guessing that the ####'s can be used to skip the first section of each line, but for the life of me I can't figure out how. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the strings:

```
String s = "TITEL####URL####ABSTRACT\n";
String[] tokens = s.split("#+");
String abstractText = tokens[2];
```

Then to count words you can split further:

```
int count = abstractText.split("\\s+").length;
```

Note: If you use Java 7+ and your file is not too big, you can also read it with:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, charset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) to find the last `####`.

So given a line you can skip over the first two parameters.

Have you tried your code? I am not familiar with `Scanner` (I will assume it allows row-by-row consumption) but it looks like you are just counting lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have fixed 4 hashes separated string, you can use this code to count the no of words:

```
   public static int countTotalWords() {
        totalWords = 0;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis;
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);


            Scanner scan = new Scanner(fis);

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String wordsString = scan.next().substring(str.lastIndexOf("####") + 4, str.length());
                String[] wordsArr = wordsString.split(" ");
                int noOfWords = wordsArr.length;
                totalWords = totalWords + noOfWords;

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Opgave1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return totalWords;
    }
```